# Array programming - Tict Tac Toe nxn board for n players

Tags: java, arrays, interface

This Piece of code is a part a of a larger project that makes a ti tac toe game for n players on a nxn board, it represents the board of the tic tac toe game.

```
/** represents a tic tac toe board of a given size */
public class TTTBoard {

/** 2-dimensional array representing the board
 * coordinates are counted from top-left (0,0) to bottom-right (size-1, size-1)
 * board[x][y] == 0   signifies free at position (x,y)
 * board[x][y] == i   for i > 0 signifies that Player i made a move on (x,y)
 */
private int[][] board;

/** size of the (quadratic) board */
private int size;

/** This private static integer i used to make a counter
 */
private static int movecount = 0;

/** constructor for creating a copy of the board
 * not needed in Part 1 - can be viewed as an example 
 */
public TTTBoard(TTTBoard original) {
        this.size = original.size;
        for (int y = 0; y < this.size; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < this.size; x++) {
                this.board[x][y] = original.board[x][y];
            }
        }
    }

/** constructor for creating an empty board for a given number of players */
public TTTBoard(int numPlayers) {
        this.size = numPlayers+1;
        this.board = new int[this.getSize()][this.getSize()];
    }

/** checks whether the board is free at the given position */
public boolean isFree(Coordinate c) {
       if (board[c.getX()][c.getY()] == 0) {
           return true;
       } else {
           return false;
           }
    }

/** returns the player that made a move on (x,y) or 0 if the positon is free */
public int getPlayer(Coordinate c) {
        if (isFree(c) == true){
            return board[c.getX()][c.getY()];
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }

/** record that a given player made a move at the given position
 * checks that the given positions is on the board
 * checks that the player number is valid 
 */

public void addMove(Coordinate c, int player) {
        if (c.checkBoundaries(size, size) == true && isFree(c) == true && player >= 0 && player <= size-1){
            board[c.getX()][c.getY()] = player;
            movecount++;
        } else {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Ivalid move");
        }
    }

/** returns true if, and only if, there are no more free positions on the board */
public boolean checkFull() {
        if (movecount == size*size) {
           return true;
        } else {
           return false;
            }
    }

/** returns 0 if no player has won (yet)
 * otherwise returns the number of the player that has three in a row
 */
public int checkWinning() {
        int b = 1;
        for(int a = 1; a < size-1; a++){
        if (board[a][b] == board[a+1][b] && board[a][b] == board[a-1][b]){
            return board[a][b];
        }else if(board[a][b] == board[a][b+1] && board[a][b] == board[a][b-1]){
            return board[a][b];
        }else if(board[a][b] == board[a+1][b-1] && board[a][b] == board[a-1][b+1]){
            return board[a][b];
        }else if(board[a][b] == board[a+1][b+1] && board[a][b] == board[a-1][b-1]){
            return board[a][b];
        }
        }
        for(int a = 1; a < size-1; a++){
            if (board[b][a] == board[b+1][a] && board[b][a] == board[b-1][a]){
                return board[b][a];
            }else if(board[b][a] == board[b][a+1] && board[b][a] == board[b][a-1]){
                return board[b][a];
            }else if(board[b][a] == board[b+1][a-1] && board[b][a] == board[b-1][a+1]){
                return board[b][a];
            }else if(board[b][a] == board[b+1][a+1] && board[b][a] == board[b-1][a-1]){
                return board[b][a];
            }
            }
        return 0;
    }

/** getter for size of the board */
public int getSize() {
        return this.size;
    }
}
```

As my test of running the hole program shows that there are a problem with the addMove, why I know that is because that I get no error massages but the program does not do what I what it too:

```
public void addMove(Coordinate c, int player) {
        if (c.checkBoundaries(size, size) == true && isFree(c) == true && player >= 0 && player <= size-1){
            board[c.getX()][c.getY()] = player;
            movecount++;
        } else {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("dumpass!");
        }
    }
```

I looks like that the code does not record the moves right, and I cannot see what I do wrong here. 
x and y coordinates i the board comes from another class Coordinate, and thats why a am using getters to get them.

Comment: Just wanted to comment that I'm a fan of your error messaging.

Comment: One minor practice that could help your code readability is to use `if(isFree(c))` instead of `if(isFree(c) == true)`. The if statement will evaluate the condition. Another thing I noticed is that the `else` on your `getPlayer` method looks incorrect. I don't believe either of these would cause your problem though

Comment: "does not record the moves right" is pretty vague.  Are you sayign that that movecount value is not what you expect it to be after addMove() is called?  You might get further by using a debugger or printing out debug statements as the program executes - try log4j or just using System.out.println()

Comment: What I mean with not recording right is that it does looks like that the addmove does not store the player value on the board[x][y] to the abitary coordinate c.

Comment: what arguments are you passing to `addMove`? Could you possibly be passing 0 as the `player`? It looks like you use 0 to indicate that a space is free, but your `addMove` will allow moves with a player value of 0 which is wrong.

Comment: @DanK I've always been told that it's a bad idea to manually write your error messages. Although I understand it in this context with the `IllegalArgs`.

Comment: player cannot be 0, the least amount of players are 2. Coordinate c but the coordinate can me 0 or above. The coordinate (0,0) is the top left corner and the bottom right is (xSize-1, ySize-1) where ySize is size of the board in the y direction and x is the size of the board in the x dicretion.

Comment: I think you need to either use a debugger or print out the board after each move.  Verify that the move is in the right spot and such.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is at least a problem concerning the players and the square occupation handling. When a square is free, you set it to 0 (and your `isFree(Coordinate c)` and `getPlayer(Coordinate c)` methods are OK with that).

However, in the `addMove(Coordinate c, int player)` method, you check that `player >= 0 && player <= size - 1`. Then you set `board[c.getX()][c.getY()]` to `player`.
If there is 2 player, size equals 2, and `player` must be between 0 or 1. When it's first player's turn, `player` variable is certainly set to 0, so the board square is set to 0 too, which means the square is free. There is a confusion between "occupier player" and free status.

I think you should replace `player >= 0 && player <= size - 1` with `player > 0 && player <= size`. Thus, a free square will worth 0, a square occupied by first player will worth 1 and a square occupied by second player will worth 2.

Moreover, as @DanielJacobson stated in its comment, you should replace `isFree(c) == true` and `c.checkBoundaries(size, size) == true` with `isFree(c)` and `c.checkBoundaries(size, size)`.